# Get values of multiple fields by names in jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have this code for getting multiple `weight`

```
 <input type="number" name="myWeight" id="1A">
 <input type="number" name="myWeight" id="1B">
 <input type="number" name="myWeight" id="1C">
```

This is my current javascript lines

```
var selWeight = []; 
$('input[name="myWeight"]').each(function() {
    selWeight.push($(this).val());
});
alert(selWeight);
```

This current code is working fine and this is the output of this code

[image]

[image]

But the problem is if the user only enters this

[image]

and this is the output

[image]

What I only want is to get the text field that is not empty.

Comment: why not just check empty value before push. `if($(this).val() != '')  selWeight.push($(this).val());`

Answer (score 1):

This works fine thank you @Shree

```
   if($(this).val() != '') 
       selWeight.push($(this).val());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
$('input[name="myWeight"]').each(function() {
    selWeight.push($(this).val());
});
```

with next:

```
$('input[name="myWeight"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        selWeight.push($(this).val());
    }
});
```